# KIbana GUI Not loading with Syslog details

Tags: kibana-4

Kibana is not loading and giving below error .. restarted the elasticsearch/Logstash service ..but issue still exist ..Memory/Sapce available on the node

Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
    at https://X.X.X.X:5601/bundles/kibana.bundl[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQQBe.png)e.js?v=10000:78465:16

Answer (score 0):

What is the kibana version you are using?
Because v5.1.1 seems to have solved the issue.

You could probably remove JS client timeout, rely on backend for timeout.

As per [Kibana git commit](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/commit/0f1c5a2b7f113723f3948590e2d577f0f50ff52e), the client timeout need not be relied upon. It could rely on backend for timeout.

So, all you need to try is:

- Go to : src/kibana/services/es.js
- Set requestTimeOut to 0, as shown in the git commit.

Comment: Running Kibana Version 4.5.4

Comment: Ok, you could modify es.js file and check.

Comment: Just to confirm ..Are you refering to below

es = esFactory({
        host: esUrl,
        log: 'info',
        requestTimeout: esRequestTimeout,
        apiVersion: esApiVersion,
        plugins: [function (Client, config) {

Comment: please have a look at git commit: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/commit/0f1c5a2b7f113723f3948590e2d577f0f50ff52e

Comment: I see below after searching for es.js ..Dont see the specific path you mentioned  /opt/kibana.backup/node_modules/@spalger/numeral/languages/es.js
/opt/kibana.backup/node_modules/moment/locale/es.js
/opt/kibana.backup/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/node_modules/moment/locale/es.js
/opt/kibana.backup/src/ui/public/es.js
/opt/kibana/node_modules/@spalger/numeral/languages/es.js
/opt/kibana/node_modules/moment/locale/es.js
/opt/kibana/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/node_modules/moment/locale/es.js
/opt/kibana/src/ui/public/es.js